# Program can't find a file even though the file is on my computer

Tags: ruby, file, text

I have "text.txt" saved to my desktop, I have tried moving around where it is and re-saving it as well as renaming it. Yet it still comes back telling it cann't find text.txt. Not sure why? is it the code or the way I am saving it?

```
   #Set line_count to 0, giving a varible for # of lines
    line_count = 0
    #Setting varible text to an empty string, this is where we will collect the text 
    text = ''
    #Open the file, the each method will send EACH part of the object through the block, every time it sends a line line_count will go up 1
    #Then add each line to the variable text, now you have saved all your text in one place
    File.open("text.txt").each do |line|
      line_count += 1
      text << line
    end 
    puts "Lines: #{line_count}"
    #split up text where there are spaces to determine word count
    word_count = text.split.length
    puts "Words: #{word_count}"
    #takes the amount of charaters in the string text - stores it in a variable - then prints it to the console
    char_count = text.length
    puts "Character count: #{char_count}"
    #store the string's lengeth without the spaces using a REGEX then print to the console
    nospace_count = text.gsub(/\s+/,'').length 
    puts "Character count without spaces: #{nospace_count}"
    puts "Number of spaces: #{char_count - nospace_count}"
    #use REGEX to count the number of sentences save to var
    sentence_count = text.split(/\.|\?|!/).length
    puts "Sentences: #{sentence_count}"
    #count paragraphs using regular expression and store them in a var
    para_count = text.split(/\n\n/).length
    puts "Paragraphs: #{para_count}"
    puts "Sentences per paragraph: #{sentence_count / para_count}"
    puts "Words per sentence: #{word_count/sentence_count}"
    stopwords = %w{the a by on for of are with just but and to the my i has in}
    words = text.scan(/\w+/)
    keywords = words.select {|word| !stopwords.include?(word)}
    puts "Keywords: #{keywords.length}"
```

Comment: File.open("text.txt"): are you sure, that your program is in the same folder than your text.txt? if not try a hardcoded path like "c:\tmp\text.txt"

Comment: Please use whitespace more effectively in your code. Break things into logical blocks. This is a readability thing and your future self will thank you. Also read "[mcve]".

Comment: Instead of `File.open("text.txt").each do |line|` then reading line by line, use `File.foreach(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code and file into the same directory

Comment: The thing to remember with Ruby is it will only look in the current directory for files unless you specify otherwise. Putting it on the desktop doesn't make it magically accessible, in fact it complicates things since that path is a lot longer than in the directory where your script is, or something relative to that.

Comment: This will only work if the directory the code is in also accidentally happens to be the current working directory. The problem is that the OP is looking for the file in the current working directory, not that he is looking next to the code.

Comment: Question, is there a way to change the current directory I'm looking for the file in? sorry new to comp sci

Comment: @PaulDuca Yeah. You can hard code the path ex "c:\temp\text.txt", Or use rubys `__FILE__` thingy to program a relative path ex:  `File.dirname(__FILE__) + "\temp\text.txt"` which will look for file in folder temp in the scripts executing directory

Comment: @PaulDuca: This doesn't really have anything to do with computer science at all. Changing a directory is basic computer usage 101. In all current mainstream operating systems, the command to do so is called or at least aliased to `cd`. Alternatively, you can do it from within Ruby, the methods are called `chdir` and `cd`.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing absolute path to the file. Instead of just the file name.

If windows then use double back-slash ("\\")